# Finger scrollable UIWebView when the keyboard is up

Tags: cocoa-touch

In an application that I'm writing I have a UIWebview up top and some UITextFields at the bottom that I want the user to be able to type in depending on what's in the webview. But when they touch the Text Field and the keyboard pops up, the user loses the ability to manipulate the web page to see different parts.

Is there a way to keep the keyboard up and still be able to manipulate the UIWebView?

Answer (score 1):

No I believe the Keyboard is modal so you can't access the form underneath it.

You can respond to the

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification;
- (void)keyboardWillHidde:(NSNotification*)aNotification;
```

notifications and scroll the View up or down when the keyboard is shown...

[Example here](http://alanduncan.net/?q=node/13)